# AWS Step function level timeout with custom error handling like Catch blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is there a way in AWS Step functions to define a timeout for the whole function using the `TimeoutSeconds` field, but still take custom action (trigger a lambda) when the step function level timeout is reached ?

Here is a sample function definition,

```
{
  "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language for fanning out AWS Batch job",
  "StartAt": "Wait 60 secs",
  "TimeoutSeconds": 10,
  "States": {
    "Wait 60 secs": {
      "Type": "Task",
      .
      .
      .
      "End": true,
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.All"
          ],
          "Next": "Notify failure"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Notify failure": {
      "Type": "Task",
      \\ Push message to an sns topic
    }
  }
}
```

I want a way to call the `Notify failure` step, when the step function level time out is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably best handled by using the [Execution Status Change Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html) that [AWS Step Functions Workflows](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) will emit to [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/). You can author Rules to match events like the following, then have EventBridge send to your SNS topic or invoke a Lambda function.

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "315c1398-40ff-a850-213b-158f73e60175",
    "detail-type": "Step Functions Execution Status Change",
    "source": "aws.states",
    "account": "012345678912",
    "time": "2019-02-26T19:42:21Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
      "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:execution:state-machine-name:execution-name"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:execution:state-machine-name:execution-name",
        "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:stateMachine:state-machine",
        "name": "execution-name",
        "status": "TIMED_OUT",
        "startDate": 1551224926156,
        "stopDate": 1551224927157,
        "input": "{}",
        "inputDetails": {
             "included": true
        },
        "output": null,
        "outputDetails": null
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could break this into two state machines, with the core logic (and timeout) in one that you invoke from an "outer" state machine using the [Step Functions integration with itself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html) (aka "nesting"). And put the compensating logic in that outer workflow.

Comment: The first option seems to be a fit, I can even cover cases where the step function is aborted, which would be difficult in the second one.  Thanks for the help.